# Simulate KeyPress Enter for Google Chrome in pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to simulate Enter Key. Nothing seems to happen with my attempt to do so :

https://jsfiddle.net/jn4zy1fc/4/

```
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="field" onkeydown="test(event);">
  </form>

  <script>
     function test(ev){
        if(ev.keyCode == 13){
        alert ("enter key");
        }
     }

        field = document.getElementById("field");
        var e = document.createEvent("KeyboardEvent"); 
        e.initKeyboardEvent("keydown", true, true, window,true, false, false, false,13, 0);
        field.dispatchEvent(e);     
  </script>
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/simulate-javascript-key-events? Also, is it a requirement in your example that you use the `createEvent` api directly, or are you fine with using a library or some other method?